# I was trying to rename a CSV file in the same folder as "(today's date).csv" but I am getting path specified errors

Tags: python, csv, datetime, rename, file-rename

I was trying to rename a CSV file in the same folder as "(today's date).csv" but I am getting path specified errors.

The code I used:

```
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
d1 = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

src = 'Attendance.csv'
dst = d1+'.csv'

os.rename(src, dst)
```

The errors I got:

```
The system cannot find the path specified: 'Attendance.csv' -> '01/03/2024.csv'
```

Comment: The slash character is reserved, and always indicates a directory name. Python (or more correctly, the underlying OS `open` system call) ends up looking for a directory named `03` inside a directory named `01` in the current directory, which of course does not exist. Choose a different separator (and while you're at it, probably switch to a machine-readable date format like yyyy-mm-dd which sorts correctly etc).